# Packages and naming conventions

Tags: android

I have a class structure for handset and tablet elements: ProfileFragment(handset) and ProfileFragment(tablet) are derived from ProfileFragment(abstract).
Packages go like:

- fragments
- fragments.handset
- fragments.tablet

I'm not sure if I'm doing right with those potentially misleading duplicate class names. What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always avoid naming multiple classes (which differ in their implementation) the same. Even though you can (using different packages).

You could go with putting the your device-type in the class name. E.g.

- `AbstractProfileFragment`
- `TabletProfileFragment`
- `HandsetProfileFragment`

Those classes can (and should) still be split up into multiple packages.

Comment: I feel the same way, too. But why?